# org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: while saving Spark Dataframe

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have 1 table in 2 tables in my database.I am tring to save data from first table to second table using insertInto.

```
    CREATE TABLE if not exists dbname.tablename_csv ( id STRING, location STRING, city STRING, country STRING) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE ;

    CREATE TABLE  if not exists dbname.tablename_orc ( id String,location STRING, country String PARTITIONED BY (city string) CLUSTERED BY (country) into 4 buckets ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS ORCFILE tblproperties("orc.compress"="SNAPPY");

    var query=spark.sql("id,location,city,country from dbname.tablename_csv")
    query.write.insertInto("dbname.tablename_orc")
```

but its giving issue."

```
    "org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: `dbname`.`tablename_orc` requires that the data to be inserted have the same number of columns as the target table: target table has 3 column(s) but the inserted data has 4 column(s), including 0 partition column(s) having constant value(s).;"
```

Plese someone give me a hint what else need to add.I tried by adding partitionBy also but got same error and was showing partitionBy not Required.

```
    query.write.partitionBy("city").insertInto("dbname.tablename_orc")
```

Answer (score 0):

saveAsTable(...) with mode = "append"

Comment: Tried but i have 50 cr+ records so taking 3.5 hrs.Thats by trying  using insertInto.